# How to make a color scale with sharp transition in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I am trying to create a color scale with a sharp color transition at one point. What I am currently doing is:

```
test <- data.frame(x = c(1:20), y = seq(0.01, 0.2, by = 0.01))

cutoff <- 0.10

ggplot(data = test,
       aes(x = as.factor(x), y = y, fill = log(y), width = 1, binwidth = 0)) + 
 geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
 scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("red", "red", "yellow", "green"), 
                      values = rescale(log(c(0.01, cutoff - 0.0000000000000001, cutoff, 0.2))), 
                      breaks = c(log(cutoff)), label = c(cutoff))
```

It is producing the plots I want. But the position of the break in colorbar somehow varies depending on the cutoff. Sometimes below the value, sometimes above, sometimes on the line. Here are some plots with different cutoffs (0.05, 0.06, 0.1):

[image: cut off at 0.05] 
[image: cut off at 0.06]
[image: cut off at 0.10]

What am I doing wrong? Or alternatively, is there a better way to create a such a color scale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are still interested in a solution for this, you can add `guide = guide_colourbar(nbin = <some arbitrarily large number>)` to `scale_fill_gradientn()`. This increases the number of bins used by the colourbar legend, which makes the transition look sharper.

```
# illustration using nbin = 1000, & weighted colours below the cutoff
plot.cutoff <- function(cutoff){
  p <- ggplot(data = test,
              aes(x = as.factor(x), y = y, fill = log(y))) + 
    geom_col(width = 1) +
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("red4", "red", "yellow", "green"), 
                         values = scales::rescale(log(c(0.01, cutoff - 0.0000000000000001, 
                                                        cutoff, 0.2))), 
                         breaks = c(log(cutoff)), 
                         label = c(cutoff),
                         guide = guide_colourbar(nbin = 1000))
  return(p)
}

cowplot::plot_grid(plot.cutoff(0.05),
                   plot.cutoff(0.06),
                   plot.cutoff(0.08),
                   plot.cutoff(0.1),
                   ncol = 2)
```

[image: illustration]

(If you find the above insufficiently sharp at very high resolutions, you can also set `raster = FALSE` in `guide_colourbar()`, which turns off interpolation & draws rectangles instead.)

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into [scale_colour_steps](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_steps.html) or [scale_colour_stepsn](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_steps.html)?

Using the option `n.break` from `scale_colour_stepsn` you should be able to specify the number of breaks you want and have sharper transitions.

Be sure to use ggplot2 > 3.3.2

Comment: I wish I could give this two upvotes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I *think* it is slightly tricky to achieve an exact, discrete cutoff point in the continuous color scale using `scale_fill_gradientn`. A quick alternative would be to use `scale_fill_gradient`, set the cutoff with `limits`, and set the color of 'out-of-bounds' values with `na.value`.

Here's a slightly simpler example than in your question:

```
# some data
df <- data.frame(x = factor(1:10), y = 1, z = 1:10)

# a cutoff point
lo <- 4 

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "green",
                      limits = c(lo, max(df$z)), na.value = "red")
```

[image]

As you see, the values below your cutpoint will not appear in the legend, but one may consider including a large chunk of red a waste of "legend band width" anyway. You might just add a verbal description of the red bars in the figure caption instead.

---

You may also wish to differentiate between values below a lower cutpoint and above an upper cutpoint. For example, set 'too low' values to blue and 'too high values' to red. Here I use `findInterval` to differentiate between low, mid and high values.

```
# some data
set.seed(2)
df <- data.frame(x = factor(1:10), y = 1, z = sample(1:10))

# lower and upper limits
lo <- 3
hi <- 8

# create a grouping variable based on the the break points
df$grp <- findInterval(df$z, c(lo, hi), rightmost.closed = TRUE)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "green", limits = c(lo, hi), na.value = "red") +
  geom_bar(data = df[df$grp == 0, ], fill = "blue", stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! This is indeed a good alternative for the example in the question. But I see two problems here: 1.  values below the cutoff cannot be "weighted",  e.g.  `colours = c("red4", "red", "yellow", "green")` in my mini example 2. I think the fact that the cutoff is not illustrated in the legend makes comrpehension much harder